# jQuery serialize and return JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, serialization

I'm trying to serialize sortable list using data-id attribute instead of just id.

This is my code:

```
var obj = $('.sortable li').map(function() {
    return 'id=' + $(this).data("id");
}).get();

JSON.stringify(obj)
```

which returns:

```
["id=1", "id=2", "id=3"]
```

what I need is to return:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]
```

Here is the html part:

```
<ul class="sortable">
  <li data-id="1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-id="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-id="3">Item 3</li>
  <li data-id="4">Item 4</li>
  <li data-id="5">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using map method itself.

```
var obj = $('.sortable li').map(function() {
 return {
   id: $(this).data("id")
 };
}).get();

JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks I prefer map method instead of each.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var id = [];
$('.sortable li').each(function() {
  id.push({
    id: $(this).data('id')
  });
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(id))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable">
  <li data-id="1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-id="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-id="3">Item 3</li>
  <li data-id="4">Item 4</li>
  <li data-id="5">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Check this using `.each()` and `.push()`